# How do I get "state_enabled" in a ColorStateList to work in a Spinner?

Tags: android

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I have this ColorStateList called "voices_spinner_white_text_color_states" see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:color="@color/color_white_light_alpha" />

<item 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:color="@color/color_white" />
</selector>
```

which I have referenced in my SpinnerAdapter like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View item;

    if( convertView != null ){
        item = (GenericSpinnerItem)convertView;
    } else {
        item = new GenericSpinnerItem( context, false );
        ((GenericSpinnerItem)item ).valueText.setTextColor( context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.voices_spinner_white_text_color_states) );
        AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, M.dp(30));
        item.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    ( (GenericSpinnerItem)item ).setup(values.get(position));

    return item;
}
```

I expect when I call

```
spinner.setEnabled( false )
```

that the text for the spinner would show the disabled state. It shows the enabled state just fine but it simply doesn't show the disabled state when I change the enabled state of the spinner to false.

In fact for testing sake if I change the "android:state_enabled="false" to "android:state_enabled="**true**" like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:color="@color/color_white_light_alpha" />

<item 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:color="@color/color_white" />
</selector>
```

the "disabled state" shows up. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since I can't comment your question, I'll write an answer.]

I have experienced the exact same.

Interestingly, TextView objects can be enabled and disabled successfully and react to this setting appropriately, when they're on their own.

My assumption at this point in time is that the Spinner simply does not propagate (at least) its enabled state (change) to its child(ren), in this case the TextView in particular.

I'd consider this a bug or a design flaw since it (unnecessarily) limits the ways in which one can change a spinner's appearance out of the box, to name just one aspect.

One can, of course, subclass Spinner and deliver (at least) this event to the TextView. However, I wouldn't consider that a clean solution, unless someone can point out that Spinner conforms in this regard to an underlying design principle of Android, such that the behavior won't ever change.

**[Update 21012-Dec 7]**

Two more (accidential) findings.

First, regarding **android:addStatesFromChildren**, see my comment below.

Second, **android:disableChildrenWhenDisabled** was obviously introduced for the Holo style because the Holo Spinners wouldn't look good without the feature, see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/42b7e99b11a5ab1cbc0beebe0b15e46bdf462dff%5E!/. Despite the misnomer, if set to true, a Spinner is supposed to propagate its enabled state (*both* true *and* false, that is) to its children.

Presumably, targetting the Holo (or later) theme with your application sets this to true, while it should be false (resp. nonexistent) if you target older themes (resp. Android releases).

It appears that for the time being, dealing with this attribute explicitly in Eclipse might be problematic because of a rather late addition for it in the Eclipse plugin, see [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/8381e23ec6d557059d15c73ea313d8324359f762%5E2..8381e23ec6d557059d15c73ea313d8324359f762/](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/42b7e99b11a5ab1cbc0beebe0b15e46bdf462dff%5E!/)

In other words, when one develops for a Holo enabled device or above, one can expect Spinners to propagate their enabled state to their children. With Android 2  devices still selling and having a bit of a market share as of today, in many cases one will have to live with the older Spinners which do not work as expected out of the box.

Comment: Thanx class, indeed I think for now I'm going to do just as you said propagate the enabled state to the TextView. I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Oops. Just came across **android:addStatesFromChildren**, attribute of android.view.ViewGroup. Spinner inherits. As per the docs, if set to true, ViewGroup would "for example appear to be focused when its child EditText or button is focused". One would set the state of the TextView and the Spinner would be informed. Question is, does the ViewGroup propagate the state change of the TextView to the other children? If so, would any child's state change be propagated to all other children as well as the view group? How the heck does one "add" boolean attribute values from children, anyway?